# @autowired vs new key?

Tags: spring

What is the difference using `@Autowired` annotation and `new` key ?
Let's within a class what would be the difference between :

```
@Autowired private UserDao userdao;
```

and

```
private UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
```

Is there an impact on the performance?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Besides low coupling, that others have already touched on, a major difference is that with the `new` approach, **you get a new object every time**, whether you want to or not. Even if `UserDaoImpl` is reusable, stateless and threadsafe (which DAO classes should strive to be) you will still create new instances of them at every place they are needed.

This may not be a huge issue at first, but consider as the object graph grows - the `UserDaoImpl` perhaps needs a Hibernate session, which needs a DataSource, which needs a JDBC connection - it quickly becomes a lot of objects that has to be created and initialized over and over again. When you rely on `new` in your code, you are also spreading out initialization logic over a whole bunch of places. Like in this example, you need to have code in your UserDaoImpl to open a JDBC connection with the proper parameters, but all other DAO classes have to do the same thing.

And here is where Inversion-of-Control (IoC) comes in. It aims to address just these things, by decoupling object creation and life-cycle from object binding and usage. The most basic application of IoC is a simple Factory class. A more sophisticated approach is Dependency Injection, such as Spring.

**Is there an impact on the performance?**

Yes, but it's most likely not going to be very significant. Using Springs dependency injection costs a little more in startup-time as the container has to be initialized and all managed objects set up. However, since you won't be creating new instances of your managed objects (assuming that is how you design them), you'll gain some runtime performance from less GC load and less object creation.

Your big gain however is going to be in maintainability and robustness of your application.

Answer (score 8):

The above comments are correct, but here I am going add some example that helps to you.

Look We have 100 Classes that uses `UserDao` class, And you get dao instance like that:
`private UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();` in 100 places,

After few weeks the requirement changed and we need to use `LdapUserDao` or something similar

```
class LdapUserDao implements UserDao{

}
```

that implements `UserDao`. What do you do? How do you handle your `new` keywords, You tied impl class into usage.

If you use @Autowired in 100 places then from one place (if you use xml based config then, just go xml and switch to another UserDao from xml, if annotation the go to that component and switch Spring annotation to proper one) manage it, so in 100 places it appears. This is what is called `DI` pattern. This is whole purpose of [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Another important thing is with spring annotation even you can manage object scope, but with new keyword no way(unles you do dumb singleton or something like that), 
I am sure with new keyword you can no have

```
  Prototype
  Request
  Single
```

Scoped objects

In terms of performance, It is quite difficult to say, unless to see your code. But I am sure at worst case they may have equal performance, otherwise springs way is fast, because As I know dao class should be singleton, not prototype, so whole project you will have on userdao object in spring way, with `new` way It depends where you are loosing reference to dao object. But Leave the performance. Do not consider performance over good design. All time 1st make it in good manner(not fast manner) with good design, then look it's performance.

Answer (score 3):

You will get NullPointerException if you use

```
private UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
```

because it doesn't set the session reference that was declared in the *context.xml.

Comment: thanks , i faced this probs and suck a day to resolve it..,

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, you'll get a `UserDaoImpl` instance asigned in the `userdao` attribute in both cases.

But the first approach implies the ussage of the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern, that has some advantages over the second approach:

- Your class now depends on an Interface, so it can work with any implementation of UserDao (maybe one that uses and RDBMS, other that uses XML files as a repository)
- As you depend on an Interface now, Unit Testing and Mocking are pretty easy and straightforward.
- [Low-coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) is nice attribute to have in your code.

So you should prefer the second approach over the first, specially if your already using Spring (that's the idea behind an [Inversion-Of-Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container)