# In spring when to use new keyword and autowired keyword

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am new to spring. i am confused when to use autowired keyword and new keyword.while using the model class in spring we use new keyword rather than Autowired keyword

Comment: `new` and `@Autowired` are fairly different things.  The former creates a new instance of a Java object, deemed to live only so long as it is being referred to in some scope.  `@Autowired` on the other hand tells Spring to create a new instance of some bean, and manage that bean in the Spring context.

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12849561/1480381)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@autowired vs new key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849561/autowired-vs-new-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new keyword allocated new memory space in the heap for the object. Then the constructor will initialize the state of the object (properties of the object).

The @Autowired asks Spring framework to inject the requests **bean by type**.

Now, you have built an application which has a controller, service and dao layer. These layers basically doesn't hold state of the application/business data. They wrap functionalities. Business logic/Logic to talk to db , etc. So from Service when you want to call a save(entity) in dao layer you will do -> new DAO().save(entity)...... This is a wastage of memory as the you creating new Object everytime just to use the functionality. An efficient way to do so is -> Create singleton Service instance -> one instance for entire application and then inject them in other places to use the functionality.

Spring handles that for you.. @Service/@REstController/@Component basically tells Spring to create an instance of that class for you - default scope is Singleton. And wherever you mention -> @Autowired, it injects that bean (by type) to the requested class for you to use the functionality.

This is basically inversion of control. Way I keep this is mind is handling the responsibility/control of creating instances and injecting them in places you need is inversed from you to the framework. And also you removing the strong coupling by injecting by type (interface generally) and spring finds the impl of the interface and injects it whereevr you mentioned @Autowired. In case there are multiple impls you need to name each impl (or default name is the class name with firstLetter small case - please confirm this once cause I dont remember correctly) and use @Qualified(name) to mention to spring which impl you want to inject.

Now your model/entity -> These are basically Java beans -> having properties and accesor methods to access those properties. These will hold state of your application. So every time a new User registers you need a new User object to pass around the layers to perform some logic and then save to the DB. So you will create a new Object with new keyword.

Comment: This is a nice explaination -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849561/autowired-vs-new-key

Comment: Thankx priyak Dey..  learnt the Core Spring lot of them by this comment

Comment: in spring how to check that the given the class is singleton?

Comment: Your concrete classes annotated with @Component/@Service/@Repository/@Controller/@RestController will be singleton by default.

Factory methods annotated with @Bean, return types would be Singleton.
Singleton is the default scope unless mentioned explicitly by using @Scope(<scope-type>)

Comment: @Sangam.R.Ingalalli - NOTE:  There is a typo error. the annotation is **@Qualifier and not Qualified**... I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The typical use of @Autowire is to automatically fill a property, when initializing a bean, with a singleton dependency. If it is really a dependency that should be initialized once and reused.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question how to check scope of bean, there is ConfigurableApplicationContext which sub class of ApplicationContext, which again is the subclass of BeanFactory. There is a method on configurableApplicationContext::getBeanFactory which returns you the BeanFactory. You can invoke various methods on it to check the scope of various beans.
Here is the code snippet I wrote:

```
@Component
public class ScopeTestService {

@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void testScope() {
    String scope = applicationContext.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("scopeTestService").getScope();
    System.out.println(scope);
}

}
```

You can person various permutation combinations to check. You can change using @Scope("scope type") annotation along with @Component.

The result for the above code:
2020-01-29 02:24:56.125  INFO 57500 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-01-29 02:24:57.604  INFO 57500 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-29 02:24:58.066  INFO 57500 --- [           main] c.example.demo.JpaTutorialsApplication   : Started JpaTutorialsApplication in 7.023 seconds (JVM running for 7.837)
***singleton***
2020-01-29 02:24:58.077  INFO 57500 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-29 02:24:58.082  INFO 57500 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-29 02:24:58.098  INFO 57500 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.