# Is Spring Boot Autowired for object creation better than manual object creation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-integration

Which below case will give me better performance

1. Using Spring Boot Autowired annotation for creating an object
   Or
2. Using new key for creating an object.

I understand with spring annotations will have a choice of using lot more inbuilt features.

Kindly help me to understand

Comment: This is what you're looking for Muthu. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849561/autowired-vs-new-key

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn an Inversion of Control pattern first of all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Then you need to make yourself familiar with Spring Framework as an implementation of it: https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework

In two words answering your question: the Spring way with its dependency injection is much better by performance at runtime, then manual `new` managing. Just because Spring instantiates objects only once, at start up (mostly) and then provide you those ready objects. With `new` you have to manage then yourself and in most cases you lose with GC and memory (de)allocation.