# Spring boot @Autowired vs Dynamic Polymorphism in case of loose coupling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, loose-coupling

Hi I guess this question is quite basic but please help out!!!

Let say I have one interface Write and 2 implementing classes Pen and Pencil

```
public interface Write {
    
    public void writeSomething();
}

public class Pen implements Write {

    @Override
    public void writeSomething() {
        System.out.println("Writing using Pen!!");
    }
}

public class Pencil implements Write {

    @Override
    public void writeSomething() {
        System.out.println("Writing using Pencil!!");
    } 
    
}

public class Test1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Write wr = new Pen();
        wr.writeSomething();
    }
}

public class Test2 {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Pen")
    private static Write wr;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        wr.writeSomething();
    }
}
```

Now,
How does **Test2 class implementation** of spring boot is **better** then **Test1 class implementaion**, in terms of **loose coupling** in java.
And what is the **benefit of @Autowired** then ?

Comment: In the 2nd example, we have no coupling in the source code on class `Pen`.

Comment: Having to not write (new) everywhere in the code.  Springboot handles initialization and injection and keeps track of the instances and that is where @Autowired comes in

Comment: I think the response of this question you will find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849561/autowired-vs-new-key

Comment: Still unable to understand which is better and if this is only benefit of autowiring then why use it at all

Comment: When using @Autowired you are injecting a bean to a specific place which is in 95% of the cases created only once when you run your app and after that, it is being reused.
In your approach, you are creating a new object every time. Now imagine if your code does that 300 times.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Autowired` annotation create a single `Object(Bean)` that your application reused instead of creating new Object each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fifth principle of SOLID - Dependency inversion. You need use interfaces, and don't use implementations.

One of advantages is when you create Test2 you can manage which implementation you will use. For example you can create both new Test2(Pen) or new Test2(Pencil) dependent on your requirements.Spring will create Test2 with any Writer implementation. But with Test1 you can't manage Writer implementation.

Also it gives possibility to easy test Test2 with Writer mocks.

@Autowired will inject Writer bean into Test2 bean. You have to add @Component or @Service annotation above Test2 class or create Test2 bean configuration in class with @Configuration.